# Getting data attribute from td returns undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm not sure if this is correct but I'm trying to get a `data` attribute from a `td` instead of a `tr`. I have a data-id attribute there already.

```html
<tbody>
<?php $offset = $this->uri->segment(5,0)+1; ?>
<?php foreach($user as $row): ?>
<tr data-id="<?php echo $row->id; ?>">
<td><?php echo $offset++; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row->company; ?></td>
<td data-company="<?php echo $row->id; ?>"><input type="hidden" class="id" name="id" value="<?php echo $row->id; ?>"/><input type="button" class="expandlink_admin" value="+"/></td>
<td><input type="hidden" class="id" name="id" value="<?php echo $row->id; ? >"/><input type="button" class="shrinklink_admin" value="-"/></td>
<td><input type="hidden" class="id" name="id" value="<?php echo $row->id; ?>"/><input type="hidden" name="company" value="<?php echo $row->id; ?>"/><input type="hidden" name="set" value="edit"/><input type="button" class="editlink_company" value="Edit"/></td>
<td><input type="hidden" class="id" name="id" value="<?php echo $row->id; ?>"/><input type="hidden" name="company" value="<?php echo $row->id; ?>"/><input type="hidden" name="set" value="delete"/><input type="button" class="deletelink" value="Delete"/></td>
</tr>
<tr class="subtable">
<td colspan="9">
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row->id; ?>"/>
<table class="table">
<tr>
<td>Total Agents : </td>    
<td id="totalagents"></td>
<td>Address : </td>
<td><?php echo $row->address; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Total Users : </td>
<td id="totalusers"></td>
<td>Date Added : </td>
<td><?php echo $row->date_added; ?></td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</tbody>
```

```js
$('.expandlink_admin').on('click', function() {
var $row = $(this).closest('tr');
var curr_row = $row.data('id');
var company = $(this).closest('td').data('company');
// console.log(curr_row);
console.log(company);
 var row = $(this).parents("tr");
 $.ajax({
    url: '/manager/administrator/users/count_agents',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType:'json',
    data:{id:curr_row},
    cache:false,
    success:function(result){
    //console.log(result);
     $(".subtable").each(function() { //loop through each row
            if($("[type='hidden']", this).val() == curr_row) { 
                  $(this).show();
                 row.find('.expandlink_admin').hide();
                 row.find('.shrinklink_admin').show();
             }
     });
}});
});
```

So far it keeps returning an undefined value. Please help

Comment: What is `this` a reference to? Seeing the whole event handler would help.

Comment: `$(this).closest('tr').attr('data-id')` try this way which ever td your clicking this will get the parent row and its `attr`

Comment: You need to give more context to the problem, where is this code snippet placed?

Comment: Sorry, didn't know that wasn't enough information. I am already getting the correct item from data-id. I want to get the company name from data-company which is situated in the td

Comment: Thanks for updating the question - I added an answer for you.

Comment: what is the id of the table that contain the '.expandlink_admin' button???

Comment: The table has no id, just a bootstrap class called table

Comment: try the code i have just posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your chained `parent()` calls are going too high up the DOM to get the parent `tr` element. Instead, you can use `closest()`. Also note it's better practice to use `data()` to retrieve data attributes. Try this:

```
var $row = $(this).closest("tr");
var rowid = $row.data('id');
var company = $(this).closest('td').data('company');
```

Here's a complete example

```
$('.expandlink_admin').on('click', function() {
    var $row = $(this).closest("tr");
    var rowid = $row.data('id');
    var company = $(this).closest('td').data('company');

    $.ajax({
        url: '/manager/administrator/users/count_agents',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType:'json',
        data: {
            id: rowid    
        },
        cache: false,
        success: function(result) {
            $(".subtable").each(function() { //loop through each row
                if ($("[type='hidden']", this).val() == rowid) { 
                    $(this).show();
                    $row.find('.expandlink_admin').hide();
                    $row.find('.shrinklink_admin').show();
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. I've changed it and the ID appears. However, the company still doesnt show up. It still says undefined

Comment: What specifically isn't working? Have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: I've updated my code in the question. Um may I ask why are there $ behind some variables?

Comment: It's just a naming convention to indicate the variable contains a jQuery object.

Comment: Hello, I updated the code again. However, the console just prints out the id for some reason

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var curr_row = $(this).parent('tr').attr('data-id');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var curr_row = $(this).parent().attr('data-id');
var curr_comp = $(this).data('company');
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to understant what `this` stands for.
But if `$(this)` is input then it should be:

```
var curr_row = $(this).parents('tr').attr('data-id');
var curr_comp = $(this).parent().data('company'); //<-- parent() added
```

And if  `$(this)` is `td` then it should be:

```
var curr_row = $(this).parent('tr').attr('data-id');
var curr_comp = $(this).data('company');
```

Comment: I've updated the code. $this refers to a td that is being clicked.

Comment: you use `$('.expandlink_admin').on('click', function() {`. In your code `expandlink_admin` is `input` inside `td` so `$(this)` refers to `input`. You have to use: `var curr_row = $(this).parents('tr').attr('data-id'); var curr_comp =  (this).parent().data('company');`

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
        //$("#dvTable").hide();
        $("#btnGenerate").click(function () {

            szTr = '<tr data-id="test_data_id">'
            szTr = szTr + '<td>first</td>'
            szTr = szTr + '<td>company</td>'
            szTr = szTr + '<td data-company="data_company"><input type="hidden" class="id" name="id" value="row_id"/>'
            szTr = szTr + '<input type="button" class="expandlink_admin" value="+"/>'
            szTr = szTr + '</td>'
            szTr = szTr + '<td><input type="hidden" class="id" name="id" value="row_id"/><input type="button" class="shrinklink_admin" value="-"/></td>'
            szTr = szTr + '<td><input type="hidden" class="id" name="id" value="row_id"/><input type="hidden" name="company" value="row_id"/><input type="hidden" name="set" value="edit"/><input type="button" class="editlink_company" value="Edit"/></td>'
            szTr = szTr + '<td><input type="hidden" class="id" name="id" value="row_id"/><input type="hidden" name="company" value="row_id"/><input type="hidden" name="set" value="delete"/><input type="button" class="deletelink" value="Delete"/></td>'
            szTr = szTr + '</tr>'

            $('#display tbody').append(szTr);

        });


        $('body').on('click', '.expandlink_admin', function () {
                var curr_row = $(this).parent().parent('tr').attr('data-id');
                alert(curr_row)
        });


    });



</script>
</head>
<body>
     <input type="button" value="Generate" id="btnGenerate">
     <table id="display">
<tbody>



</tbody>

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why do you need to post 2 answers for the same question?

Comment: @guradio still the poster ddnt respond